# How to edit/reassign Chrome Devtools keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, keyboard-shortcuts

There's supposed to be an edit button for each shortcut in devtools. It was or still is an experimental flag to show the edit buttons. I am not seeing this option in the flags section. The information I found so far seems outdated or not applicable.

How does one edit the debugger shortcuts? In particular, I want to reassign the F8 button for resuming debugging to F5.

[image]

Comment: It's an [experiment inside devtools settings](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-88/#keyboard-shortcuts), not a flag.

Answer (score 1):

> Enable "Enable keyboard shortcut editor" in the Experiments, using `Cmd+Shift+P` or `Ctrl+Shift+P` > Show Experiments> Reload DevTools.

1. Press `Cmd+Shift+P` or `Ctrl+Shift+P` to launch the Command Menu > Type "Shortcuts" > Press Enter.
2. Click the "Edit" icon next to the shortcut. Apply the shortcut and Save.

More info:
https://www.canidev.tools/set-keyboard-shortcuts/chrome

Comment: Damn, no longer seeing this option in the experiments tab.